# Bootstrap Modal not closing on data dismiss (Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a rails application with an edit modal. The submit functionality works, but the close buttons do not do anything.

*Edit.js.erb:*

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'users/edit') %>");
```

*_edit.html.erb*

```
<div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
 <%= form_for @user,url: root_path,:method => :GET do |f|%> 
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
     <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
     <%# submit_tag 'Cancel', :type => :reset, :class => "btn btn-danger", "data-dismiss" => "modal", "aria-hidden" => "true" %>
<% end %> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The lines from the view that opens and houses the modal

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Password', edit_path(user.id),  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  

......


<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

I have the gems set up. `//= require bootstrap/modal` and `//= require jquery`are in my *application.js*

Edit: Full *application.js*

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require jquery
```

Comment: Which other .js file are included in your application.js files?

Comment: @Rohit see the edit

Comment: You need to simply add "//= require jquery_ujs". If that doesn't works too, require the latest jquery, jquery ui and bootstrap..

Comment: Done, no change @Rohit

Comment: Did you try adding jquery before the gem in the application.js file?

Comment: Before which Gem? @SebastiánPalma

Comment: Before the `require bootstrap/modal`, I've tried to reproduce your workflow, but I couldn't, do you have a repo?

Comment: I did and it did not change anything. I have a repo, should I send it?

Comment: I've cloned the repo and I don't see nothing working, are you using any gem for that modal? which one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148259/discussion-between-btuman-and-sebastian-palma).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `bootstrap-modal-rails` gem would work with a Rails 4 application version, you could consider just using the Bootstrap modals to ge it work.

You can create a modal div, then add the button which will make a request to a certain method in the controller, which will respond with a js file, that then will render the partial which will fill the modal div.

In your `index.html.erb` you can set the `link_to helper`:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Password', edit_path(user), remote: true, data: { toggle: 'modal', 'target': '#modal-window' } %>
...
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade " id="modal-window" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

This specifies the path, in this case the one that responds to the `edit` method in the `UsersController`, add the `remote: true` option to start an asynchronous request to such method, and specifiy as data attributes the `data-toggle` and `data-target`.

Then, in the bottom if you prefer, you can create the `#modal-window` div, setted to work as a bootstrap modal, and which most match in `id` and `data-target` with the `link_to` helper to be "opened".

The route that's defined in the `link_to` expects an `id`, and use the alias option to create a short version:

```
get 'users/edit/:id', to: 'users#edit', as: 'edit'
```

Your controller just needs the method, `edit`, which will respond in Javascript, it just receives the `id` param that's sent:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

As `edit` responds in json format, then you need to create a file with the same name of your method plus the extension `js` and `erb`, this is `edit.js.erb`, and contains the code to render the `_edit` partial, and show the modal:

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= j render 'users/edit' %>");
$('#modal-window').modal('show')
```

Finally the `_edit` partial will contain the content that will be added to the div modal created before, this can be easily tweaked, in the `.modal-body` div, so you can add the form:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= form_for @user, url: edit_path do |f|%> 
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %><br>
        <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %> 
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note this depends on Bootstrap, so you need to add the gem to your `Gemfile` file, and configure both js and css application files:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

# application.js
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

# application.scss
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

In the application.js, as bootstrap depends on jQuery, this must be added before the bootstrap one, and for the css configuration, the file must be `scss` in order to make the proper `import`'s.